# zip construction in folder using maven assembly

Tags: pom.xml

I'm able to construct a zip, happy. But when I unzip, the content is not packed in one folder(my file name). I saw many questions and followed, all are similar but nothing cleared this. Can anyone help me in this making zip.
Thanks in advance.......

```
<build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <target>${maven.compile.target}</target>
                <source>${maven.compile.source}</source>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includePom>true</includePom>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
             <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                     <configuration>
                         <target>
                             <property name="version" value="${maven.version}" />
                             <property name="timestamp" value="${timestamp}" />
                             <property name="revision" value="${buildNumber}" />
                             <property name="basedir" value="${maven.basedir}" />
                             <property name="targetdir" value="${project.build.directory}" />
                             <property name="workbench.jar" value="${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${project.packaging}" />

                             <!-- build timestamp -->
                             <echo file="${targetdir}/generated-resources/META-INF/build-timestamp.txt">Version: ${project.version} / Revision: ${revision} / Build: ${timestamp}</echo>

                             <!-- start scripts -->
                             <mkdir dir="${targetdir}/start" />
                             <copy todir="${targetdir}/start" overwrite="true">
                                 <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/main/start" />
                             </copy>
                             <replace dir="${targetdir}/start">
                                 <replacefilter token="@workbench.jar@" value="${workbench.jar}" />
                                 <replacefilter token="@version@" value="Version: ${project.version} / Revision: ${revision} / Build: ${timestamp}" />
                                 <replacefilter token="@versionnumber@" value="${project.version}" />
                             </replace>
                             <chmod dir="${targetdir}/start" perm="+x" includes="**/*.sh" />
                         </target>
                     </configuration>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>run</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
        </plugin>                  
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                <workspace>.</workspace>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.Workbench</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix />
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <X-Compile-Source-JDK>${maven.compile.source}</X-Compile-Source-JDK>
                        <X-Compile-Target-JDK>${maven.compile.target}</X-Compile-Target-JDK>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pack-workbench</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <attach>true</attach>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/workbench-assembly.xml</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/workbench-ri-assembly.xml</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/workbench-cxf-assembly.xml</descriptor>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/workbench-axis2-assembly.xml</descriptor>  
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>mac-workbench</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <attach>true</attach>
                        <finalName>CMIS Workbench ${project.version}.app</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>
                              src/main/assembly/workbench-mac-assembly.xml
                            </descriptor>  
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                 </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.webstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jnlp-inline</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <libPath>lib</libPath>
                <jnlp>
                    <mainClass>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.Workbench</mainClass>
                </jnlp>
                <pack200>true</pack200>
                <gzip>true</gzip>

                <sign>
                    <keystore>${project.build.directory}/keystore</keystore>
                    <keypass>password</keypass>
                    <storepass>password</storepass>
                    <alias>webstart</alias>

                    <validity>365</validity>
                    <dnameCn>OpenCMIS Development Team</dnameCn>
                    <dnameOu>Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS</dnameOu>
                    <dnameO>The Apache Software Foundation</dnameO>

                    <verify>true</verify>

                    <keystoreConfig>
                        <delete>true</delete>
                        <gen>true</gen>
                    </keystoreConfig>
                </sign>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a bit mistake in xml file under assemblies directory. Where we need to set "true" for baseIncludeDirectory tag....